# In subform of a MS Access form, how to hide/show the vertical scroll bars as needed?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subform in an MS Access form which is not hiding/showing the vertical scroll bars as needed.  In the example picture, the vertical scroll bar is showing even though there aren't enough records to warrant vertical scrolling.  How do I get the scroll bars to show only when they are needed? Do I need to add an if-then condition to the on_load event? or is there an easier option?

[Example http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/37834d1d76.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/37834d1d76.jpg)

Comment: Does it show if there is only one record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find something on these lines suits:

```
 If Me.Recordset.RecordCount > 10 Then
      Me.ScrollBars = 2 ''Vertical only
 Else
      Me.Scrollbars = 0 ''Neither
 End If
```

Comment: I just dropped it into the Form_Load event of my subform.  Works fine.

Comment: If it's a subform with Master/Child links defined, you'd likely be better to put the code in the OnCurrent of the parent form.